# How to clear routeReuseStrategy manually in Angular 7?

Tags: angular

I have a scenario where I need to clear all stored route handlers manually from the component, so that's why I created the following method in custom route reuse strategy and called in component

```
 deactivateAllHandles(): void {
    this.handlers = {};
  }
```

But it's not working? any idea?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to provide a reliable answer without seeing the code of your custom route reuse strategy class. It however typically contains a `Map` that keeps track of individual  paths and corresponding detached route handle as shown below.

```
private routeHandles = new Map<string, DetachedRouteHandle>();
```

If this is also the case in your custom route reuse strategy class, the `clear` method could look as follows:

```
clear() {
   this.routeHandles.clear();
}
```